how can i take the output of play-book in ansible with specific code and keep it in excel file,
how can i take the output of play-book in ansible with specific code and keep it in excel file, such as show configuration and the output puts it in excel file in yaml code
Iam trying to save out of network automation in excel file to present my report
---name: Manage GNS3 Cisco LAB
hosts: all
gather_facts: false
connection: local

tasks:
  - name: run multiple commands
    ios_command: 
      commands:
        - show interface status
        - show version | in uptime
        - show int | in line protocol|MTU
        - show configuration
        - show ip int bri
        # - show int | in line protocol is up
        # - show interface desc
        # - show cdp neighbors
        # - show arp
    register: if_data

  - name: print command output
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ if_data.stdout }}"

this code i need modify it or add lines to keep out in excel file
